# Core Data, Load data into UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitextview, magicalrecord

I want to be able to load the data i have in Core Data.

I figured out how to save it, but to load it it throws a __NSarray length error, how ever NSLog can read the data just fine??!?

I'm trying to have my `UITextView` populated with data from core data

I'm using MagicalRecord to manage my Core Data

[image]

```
    NSArray *people = [TextView MR_findByAttribute:@"belongsTo" withValue:@"barneDaabStartSide" andOrderBy:nil ascending:NO];
    textView1.text = [people valueForKey:@"textDataView"];
```

I also tried this :

```
NSMutableString *textViewText = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString *str in people) {
    [textViewText appendFormat:@"%@\n", str];
    self.textView1.text = textViewText;
}
```

But then it just writes all sort of code and then my string "data" so this isn't working properly

Comment: If which line / function / class does it happen exactly ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski  on textView1.text = ....

Comment: NSArray *people;
textView1.text = [people valueForKey:@"textDataView"]; // <- call of dictionary and not of array

Comment: @geo ??? what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line would be returning an array of TextView instances - or nil.

```
NSArray *people = [TextView MR_findByAttribute:@"belongsTo" withValue:@"barneDaabStartSide" andOrderBy:nil ascending:NO];
```

This should get you started.

```
NSArray *people = [TextView MR_findByAttribute:@"belongsTo" withValue:@"barneDaabStartSide" andOrderBy:nil ascending:NO];

if(people)
    for(TextView *textView in people) {
        textView1.text = textView.textDataView;
    }
}
```

Are you only trying to get one single `TextView` instance?  Then you may consider using this instead (or a similar method, check out MagicalRecord's documentation):

```
TextView *textView = [TextView MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"belongsTo" withValue:@"barneDaabStartSide"];

if(textView) {
    textView1.text = textView.textDataView;
}
```

Comment: for some reason i can't find the MacialRecord documentation. all links are black and only 1 blue i can click on.

Comment: Here's the most relevant methods for what you're doing: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MagicalRecord/2.2/Categories/NSManagedObject+MagicalFinders.html

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detail for the single TextView.  On another note, I'd consider renaming your `TextView` model to something like `Info` - and `textDataView` to `text`.  It will make a little more sense when you're writing/reading your code.